# jQM - Possible to revert back to a regular icon within a ui-alt-icon wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, icons

I am using jQuery Mobile's collapsible box, and I would like to use the alternate, black icon color for the collapse's header. This is easy to achieve by applying the ui-alt-icon class.

My problem is, I then want to use the regular, white icons within the collapsible box, on some buttons. Because the ui-alt-icon is applied to the collapsible wrapper, everything inside the collapsible is also getting the alternate, black icons. I can't seem to figure out how to tell the buttons inside the collapsible to go back to using the regular icons.

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon">
        <h3>Collapse Header</h3>
        <a href="#" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" class="ui-icon ui-disc-icon" data-icon="edit">Press Me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought maybe adding the class ui-icon to the buttons would override the ui-alt-icon, but that didn't seem to work. Can I turn the children of the ui-alt-icon wrapper back into a regular icon? I'd like to do it within the framework, and without having to resort to CSS overrides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the classes (ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon) to the header element so that the content does not inherit them:

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right" >
         <h3 class="ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon">Collapse Header</h3>
         <a href="#" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" class="ui-icon ui-disc-icon" data-icon="edit">Press Me</a>

    </div>
</div>
```